# Object variable or with block variable not set w/ for loop

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to replace text in a word document from the entries in Excel. When I run the code without the tag for-loop (that means with single tag-value combination) it works as normal. But, I insert the `wdDoc.StoryRanges` loop inside the outer tags loop I am getting the error

> "Object variable or with block variable not set"

despite setting the `wdDoc` value before the outer loop.

Can any of you please advise.

Thank you very much!

```
Public Function Test(filepath as String) As Variant
counter = 0

Dim wdApp As Object
Dim wdDoc As Object

Set wdApp = CreateObject("word.application")
wdApp.Visible = True

Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(filePath)

For Each tag In tags
  counter = counter + 1
  If Len(tag) > 0 Then
    Dim wdRng As Word.Range
    For Each wdRng In wdDoc.StoryRanges <-- [I am getting the error here]
        With wdRng.Find
            .Text = tag
            .Highlight = True
            With .Replacement
                .Text = values(counter, 1)
                .Highlight = False
            End With
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With
        Set wdApp = Nothing: Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdRng = Nothing
    Next wdRng
   End If
Next tag
End Function
```

Comment: I'm guessing `StoryRanges` isn't set? Is the file actually opening?

Comment: Use `Option Explicit` on top of your code see [Option Explicit Statement (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-explicit-statement)

Answer (score 1):

That error usually means the variable is not set. if you add a watcher at the wdDoc.StoryRanges you might see if that variable is set or not.  Or even possible wdRng  is not set, Then you might have to use a counter Index, and use while loop to do your task.

Comment: With few iterations, I realized that wdRng did not set. I had to create another variable in side the for-loop and sRng and set it to wdRng.